# SIMULINK: Repeat subsystem for each element of array in workspace and recombine signal

Tags: for-loop, signals, simulink

### Repeating subsystem for each entry in array (found in workspace), save reuslts and combine everything into a matrix to save to workspace

Hi, I am running a simulation for a space-time dependent problem. I am currently obtaining the result only at 1 single location (e.g  x_ref=0.5). I have a subroutine that takes the signals  'x', applies a delay proportional to this x_ref info and outputs the resulting signal U to the workspace.

something like

```
        IN{x} -> delay {(x_ref)} -> U to workspace
```

I would like to apply this routine for each entry in my x_ref =[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, .....]; evaluate each signal, and recombine as a matrix U containing in each column the simulation values, to then save to the workspace.
e.g.

```
 for i=1:length(x_ref)
      IN{x} -> delay {(x_ref(i) )} ->assign to  U(:,i)
 end

 U to workspace
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Do you really want to do that for a `subsystem` in a model, or are you really talking about simulating a (complete) model for different values of an input parameter?

Comment: yes, only for the subsystem.